# Python Debugger Fails to Recognize a Defined Variable

Tags: python, pdb, ipdb

I am trying to view the result of a list comprehension call using Python's debugging module, pdb. However the pdb "environment" is simultaneously claiming that a variable is and is not defined, resulting in a `NameError` for a variable which pdb agrees is defined. The following is a minimal code example to duplicate the issue:

```py
import pdb
        
def main():
    bar = [0, 0, 1, 1]
    foo(bar)
        
def foo(bar):
    pdb.set_trace()

    ### pdb COMMANDS LISTED BELOW ARE CALLED HERE ###

    print([False if bar[i] == 0 else True for i in range(len(bar))])
        
main()
```

Running the following pdb commands at the point of code execution indicated above leads to the following results.

```py
(Pdb) p bar
[0, 0, 1, 1]
(Pdb) p [False if bar[i] == 0 else True for i in range(len(bar))]
*** NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
(Pdb) !print([False if bar[i] == 0 else True for i in range(len(bar))])
*** NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
(Pdb) n
[False, False, True, True]
```

Furthermore, running the code without the pdb module yields the expected result. Changing the location of the `pdb.set_trace()` method call to the `main` function has no impact on the result. What do I need to do in order to debug this list comprehension call?

Comment: Is the goal here to achieve a deep understanding of pdb or to be able to debug within a list comprehension?

Comment: The goal is to be able to debug within a list comprehension.

Comment: VSCode using either debugpy or pdb will handle these cases for you. I suspect you're running into a closure issue here -- one that most IDEs will account for at the moment. Is that a viable solution for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've stumbled upon a bug in `pdb`! `pdb`'s `print` command is not a full-blown interactive interpreter, and can struggle finding variables that intuitively *should* be easy to find, but aren't because of the underlying CPython implementation. In particular, it often fails to do so in closures and list comprehensions. [Here's a bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue26072#msg277578).

The bug report does mention a workaround though. Type `interact`, and you'll get a full blown interactive python shell in which you should be able to evaluate your list comprehension:

```
-> print([False if bar[i] == 0 else True for i in range(len(bar))])
(Pdb) p [False if bar[i] == 0 else True for i in range(len(bar))]
*** NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
(Pdb) interact
*interactive*
>>> [False if bar[i] == 0 else True for i in range(len(bar))]
[False, False, True, True]
>>>
```